# How can i return value that is inside a query function?

Tags: mysql, node.js, function, variables, return

I have just started coding Node. I have a function that name is "add" and there is a mysql query inside the function.

I can't return "row" variable which is inside of the query function.

How can i do this?

```
Broadcast.prototype.add = function (id) {
    var broadcast;
    mysql.query("SELECT * from Table WHERE Id='" + id + "'", function(err, row) {
        if(!err) {
            return row; //it didn't work
            broadcast = row; //it didn't work
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: put `if(err)` to see if an error exist which can make the program skip those lines

Comment: i tried but there is no error

Comment: try to put `console.log()` inside `if(!err)` to see if the lines run, if they do try logging the `row` and see what's stored inside

Comment: Issn't this called Async? You should add a callback function `.add = function(id, cb) { ... ... ... cb(err, row); }` Then when you run add do the following: `broadcast = new Broadcast(); broadcast.add(5,function(err, row) { console.log(row);});`

Comment: Broadcast.prototype.add = function (id) {
    var broadcast;
    mysql.query("SELECT * from Stream WHERE Id='" + id + "'", function(err, row) {
        if(!err) {
            console.log('there is no error');
            return row; //it didn't work
            broadcast = row; //it didn't work
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};

Output : there is no error

Comment: Ohh so are you connected correctly to mysql? I assumed your where as your question states that you cannot return the value from its scope

Answer (score 1):

The code after the `return` statement `(broadcast = row;)` is not excecuted.
You should make them switch position if you want to assign the value of row to broadcast. In your comments however you've written that you want the results to be added to the array broadcast. That's why in the provided awnser you'll find it is an array and the row value is added to it.

Also because it runs in async you will need some callback function when the value has been added. Otherwise logging the `broadcast` array to fast may results in a 'still' empty array.

```
Broadcast.prototype.broadcast = [];

Broadcast.prototype.add = function (id,cb) {
    // Use self or bind the function(err,row) to Broadcast instead so you can use a normal this inside that function as well
    var self = this;  
    mysql.query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id='" + id + "'", function(err, row){

        // Check for errors
        if (err) {return console.log(err);}

        // Add the value of row to the broadcast array
        self.broadcast.push(row);

        // Run the callback function
        cb();
  });
};



var broadcast = new Broadcast();
broadcast.add(id, callbackFunction = function(){

    // Here broadcast should have a value 
    console.log(broadcast.broadcast);
});
// Here broadcast is likely not to have a value yet because mysql.query is probably executed in async.
console.log(broadcast.broadcast);
```

Comment: Actually, I want to add this row in "Broadcast.prototype.broadcasts" array

Comment: after first code and in add function, i wrote "console.log(self.broadcast)". Output : []

Comment: Ok so the problem is not the code but the fact that you are not getting any results from mysql. Do you have another program that can connect to your database? Run the exact same query in that program (`"SELECT * from Table WHERE Id=[[your id]]`) and see if you get any results back. Otherwise try `("SELECT * FROM Table")` so you get all the results. Just to see if you get anything..
Are you also sure it is `Id` and not `id` and also `Tabel` and not `table`?

Comment: **SELECT * from Table WHERE Id='" + id + "'** query returned a row

Comment: in the other program or in node?

Comment: If you feel this awnser has helped you and/or is the right solution, please mark it as such, thank you :)